# My function.php file keep being removed by itself, how can I find what removes it?

Tags: file, server, directadmin

I have an old forum built on Vbulletin, and the file at the location /includes/functions.php keep being removed once or twice a day after I upload it again.
I have access to the FTP and the Directadmin panel, but I don't know how to check what keep removing it. any ideas?